# Can I launch a MariaDB RDS instance from a local snapshot in S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mariadb, amazon-rds

Can I launch a MariaDB RDS instance from a local snapshot stored in S3?

I know it is possible to launch an instance from an RDS-managed snapshot.

I'd like to know if this is possible, or if I need to restore the local snapshot on an EC2 instance and then use DMS to migrate the data to an RDS MariaDB instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't launch a MariaDB RDS instance from a backup file stored in S3. If you were using MySQL (and MySQL only as of writing), you'd be able to use [`aws rds restore-db-instance-from-s3`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/rds/restore-db-instance-from-s3.html#restore-db-instance-from-s3).

The best approach here would be to use DMS as you've mentioned.